# Android 5.0+ InputStream.read limit to 2048 bytes

Tags: inputstream

I have set buffer size to 2M, but the result of "read.length:" is always <= 2048 on Android 5.0+. Why?

```
is = connection.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 2];
int length = -1;
while ((length = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
      Log.d("read.length:"+length);
}
```